# C++ - Producer / Consumer only allow consumption in defined chunks

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, producer-consumer

There's two threads **A** (Producer) and **B** (Consumer).

The data **A** produces is only meant to be read in **chunks**, hence **B** shall only be allowed to read once **A** has produced a whole chunk.
A single piece of data is a simple struct and the chunk length is variable. For example once it could be that **B** is allowed to read after 50 pieces of data are produced, another time it might be 200.

I've found this implementation of a producer/consumer queue that I'd like to use:
https://github.com/cameron314/readerwriterqueue

My current idea is that **A** writes its data into a std::vector and then pass the std::vector into the queue. But I doubt this works since the queue does not know how much memory an std::vector will take and it wants to allocate the memory beforehand.

I hope anybody knows an easier solution for this.

Comment: Concurrent queue of chunks.

Comment: Have you tried your solution, and if so, what went wrong with storing a `std::vector` in the queue?

Comment: Your chunk is a message of variable size. If the queue your've chosen doesn't allow for variable-size messages, you need another queue.

Comment: ' A writes its data into a std::vector and then pass the std::vector into the queue' - try it and see:)

Comment: Okay, thanks guys, I just thought this might not work - as the queue that I've linked allocated memory based on the size of its items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of what you produce or consume, you will need a concurrent queue for communication between the producer(s) and the consumer(s). If we are doing it C++ style, you'll end up with something like:

```
template<typename T, typename Alloc>
class concurrent_queue;
```

(note that some libraries already give you such containers, Intel TBB for example).

The template parameter `T` is what you exchange between producers and consumers. As you asked to consume chunks, here `T = your_chunk_type`. Let's say your chunks are variable size: `Chunk = std::vector<something>`. With the lib you've linked on github, you could just use `ReaderWriterQueue<Chunk>` as the queue sharing the work.

Comment: So you say I could well use std::vector as the template parameter of the ReaderWriterQueue that I linked?

Comment: Yes you can. `std::vector<XYZ>` has a well-defined size that is known at compile time. The queue will allocate memory for its `std::vector`s, and each `std::vector` will allocate additional memory for its items

Comment: Ah okay, I think I start  to get it. It doesn't matter how many elements are in the vector, right? Since the memory of the elements in the vector is somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is just a layer that handle a memory buffer for you, in a type-safe manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can stick with a standard sized data chunk and have one or more *framing* chunks that either indicate the start and end of a message, or perhaps just a start chunk that also has the length of the message stored in it.